# How do we align text on both sides(same as justify in word) inside a bullet point(itemize)?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules

This is my exact code and the output(see the image below). I am writing this for my resume. And it will look a lot better had the text inside the points be aligned on both sides.For example, if you see, in the last words 'placerat', 'using' and 'words' are not aligned on the right side as well. (I am just explaining what I mean by Justify)
I have tried using \justifying tag and also \justifying{...text...} but still no effect. I have pasted the entire code so that you can run it exactly on your system as well. Also to mention, I use overleaf.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[headsep=0.5cm, headheight=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\definecolor{ultrablue}{RGB}{0,0,130}
\geometry{top=10mm, left = 14.11mm, right=14.11mm, bottom = 6.4mm}
% \pagestyle{} 
% \fancyhf{}

\begin{document}

\section*{\Large\textcolor{ultrablue}{KEY PROJECTS }\hrulefill}
\vspace{-0.5em}
\textbf{Justifying the texts } $\vert$ \textbf{Summer Research Project}
\raggedleft \hfill \textit{(Jun'22 - Present)}\RaggedRight\\
\textit{Prof. ABCD XYZW} $\vert$ \textit{XYZ Dept.} 
\vspace{-0.25em}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin = *,label=\raisebox{0.25ex}{\tiny$\bullet$}]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, placerat, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam 
    \vspace{-0.4em}
    \item \justifying This is a nice text and I hope to fit it in the justified format, but it is somehow not working inspite of using 'justifed' tag
    \vspace{-0.4em}
    \item This is comparatively a shorter sentence but I want it to align by just adding some spaces between words
    \vspace{-0.4em}
    \item \justifying{This text is written inside 'justifying' tag but still as it is visible, it has no effect on the alignment, even if I have used "justifying"}
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Also any idea why is the horizontal line(after Key projects) not going upto the end, and just stopping in between?

Comment: " \justifying{This text is written inside 'justifying' tag " no, `\justifying` does not take an argument, so it applies to all the following text not just the text in `{..}`  It is never needed though, as justification is the default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying `\RaggedRight` to the entire document after the first line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[headsep=0.5cm, headheight=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\definecolor{ultrablue}{RGB}{0,0,130}
\geometry{top=10mm, left = 14.11mm, right=14.11mm, bottom = 6.4mm}
% \pagestyle{} 
% \fancyhf{}

\begin{document}

\section*{\Large\textcolor{ultrablue}{KEY PROJECTS }\hrulefill\parfillskip=0pt }

\textbf{Justifying the texts } $\vert$ \textbf{Summer Research Project}
\hfill \textit{(Jun'22 - Present)}\\
\textit{Prof. ABCD XYZW} $\vert$ \textit{XYZ Dept.} 


\begin{itemize}[leftmargin = *,label=\raisebox{0.25ex}{\tiny$\bullet$}]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, placerat, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam 

    \item This is a nice text and I hope to fit it in the justified format, but it is somehow not working inspite of using 'justifed' tag
    \item This is comparatively a shorter sentence but I want it to align by just adding some spaces between words

    \item This text is written inside 'justifying' tag but still as it is visible, it has no effect on the alignment, even if I have used "justifying"
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This has solved the issue. I am not sure why I was using \raggedleft and \RaggedRight, I suppose it was to ensure that the two elements are to the extreme left and right resp. Also I am happy to have received such a quick response to my first ever post :D

Comment: They did not have the effect you wanted on that line. The `\raggedleft ` did nothing at all (as it as undone by `\RaggedRight`) and  the `\RaggedRight` then applied to the whole document.  I also removed all the negative space which should never be needed, if you want to adjust space between items, use the `itemsep` key in the list setup @Pranav-Malpure

Comment: Yes got it Sir. Thank you for your help